# How to reload a qlikview dashboard using a variable event trigger?

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to have a production/staging toggle in my dashboard. I created the toggle using Input Box with variable *vEnvironment*. Then I added a document level trigger - Variable event trigger - for *vEnvironment* - onChange - reload.

On changing the toggle i can see the value of variable getting set correctly, but it is not reloading the QVW file. Am i missing something?

Comment: Is the `.qvw` local or on the Access Point?

Comment: local. Will this be achievable on access point?